# Angular ngIf observable response with async

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I would show a loader if data is not ready without making multiple requests

So I would use `as` in order to reuse the request.

```
<div class="loading-overlay" *ngIf="this.indicatorService.loadingIndicators[this?.indicatorName] && !(values$ |async as values) && !(valuesNat$ |async as natValues) ">
  <app-loading-spinner textBloc="LOADING_DATA_IN_PROGRESS"></app-loading-spinner>
</div>
<div [hidden]="!values">
  <app-chart-multi [type]="type" [name]="indicatorName" [valuesNat]="natValues" [values]="values" [objectifs]="objectifs" (weekLegend)="displayCurrentPeriodFormat()"></app-chart-multi>
</div>
```

Actually I get error

```
[ERROR ->]<app-chart-multi [type]="type" [name]="indicatorName" [valuesNat]="natValues" [values]="values" [obje")
```

Comment: You do not need `this` inside your templates. All members are rooted in the component automatically.

Comment: You are right I will  delete it but it's not resolving my problem

Comment: this `*ngIf` condition... Just move this to typescript and use normal rxjs operators. This is just unreadable

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

`values` is available only inside of *ngIfed element.
try to use else

```
 <ng-template #loader>loading...</ng-template>
 <ng-contaier *ngIf="this.indicatorService.loadingIndicators[indicatorName] && !(values$ |async as values) && !(valuesNat$ |async as natValues); else loader">
  <app-chart-multi [type]="type" [name]="indicatorName" [valuesNat]="natValues" [values]="values" [objectifs]="objectifs" (weekLegend)="displayCurrentPeriodFormat()"></app-chart-multi>
 </ng-container>
```